# How to calculate 12 month rolling sum based on groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I am trying to calculate the 12 month rolling sum for the number of orders and revenue based on a person's name using Python for the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( columns = ['Name','Month','Orders','Revenue']) 
df['Name'] = ['Ava','Ava','Ava','Baptiste','Baptiste','Baptiste','Baptiste','Cam','Cam']
df['Month'] =['2019-07','2020-04','2021-03','2020-03','2020-10','2021-03','2021-05','2020-01','2021-03'] 
df['Orders'] =[2,12,4,5,9,10,3,4,5]
df['Revenue'] = [10,25,15,5,8,10,12,20,5]
```

In order to give the following output:

```
df['Rolling 12 Month Orders'] = [2,14,16,5,14,24,22,4,5]
df['Rolling 12 Month Revenue'] = [10,35,40,5,13,23,30,20,5]
```

The rolling sum should add up all the totals in the past 12 months grouped by the name column.

I have tried the following:

```
df['Rolling 12 Month Orders'] = df.groupby(['Name','Month'])['Orders'].rolling(12).sum()
```

but it does not give me the expected result.

Comment: Hi, did you face any issues with my answer below? Kindly let mw know, I just noticed you accepted the answer and then cancelled it. I would be glad to help. Although I had checked the code at my end before posting.

Comment: It works fine for small datasets however its taking a while for a larger set I intend to use it for so decided to wait and see if there was an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the `rolling` frequency as 12, pandas does not know that you want to specify a 12 months window, also you need to make sure that your `Month` column is identified as a date type column, try this:

```
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'])

df['Rolling 12 Month Orders'] = df.groupby(['Name']).rolling('365d', on = 'Month')['Orders'].sum().reset_index( drop = True)

df['Rolling 12 Month Revenue'] = df.groupby(['Name']).rolling('365d', on = 'Month')['Revenue'].sum().reset_index( drop = True)
```

Also, you need to use `365d` instead of `12m`, since using `12m`  would throw an error : `ValueError: <12 * MonthEnds> is a non-fixed frequency`.

A brief explanation for this is that a rolling window must have a fixed width - "a month" does not have a fixed number of days.